# Create Log File Using Linq To Xml

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to create application log file using Linq-To-Xml.
I would like to lock the file from user editing, but keep the application to update the file (radonly privilege).

Is there a way to do so using Linq-To-Xml functionalities (I'm currently uses FileInfo)?

(The framework is .Net 3.5)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing.  Linq-To-Xml and FileInfo don't really have a huge amount to do with each other.  I am guessing you are using the FileInfo class to save you linq-To-Xml document to disk.
Have a look at the FileStream class.  There are a number of overloads on the FileStream class that allow you to control access to the file you are writing to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a way to save the file as readonly using linq To Xml object?

Comment: @RoiShabtai: You would need to do that as a separate operation, making the file read only after you have saved it. This can't be done with linq-to-xml classes.